# Crear sublistas a partir de una lista añadiendo en la primera posicion el elemnto y en la segunda cuantas veces aparece

Tags: python

Dada una lista de largo `x`, necesito crear una nueva tal que se agregue un elemento en la posición `[1]` que es contador del mismo elemento. estoy intentando insertando el contador en la segunda posición

```
   def xx(lista):
      y=[lista[0],0]
     count=0
     for i in lista:
      if  i[0]==lista[0]:
       count=count+1
    z=[]
    z.append(count)
    return y
 print (xx(['a','b','c','a']))
 deseo llegar a esto:

lista 2 =(['a', 2], ['b',2], ['c', 1])
```

Comment: Hola Natalia, bienvenida a [es.so]. Te recomiendo pasarte por [tour] y [ask] para conocer por encima el funcionamiento del sitio y cómo realizar buenas preguntas. ¿Has intentado algo? si es así deberías agregarlo, que no funcione es irrelevante, sino no estaríamos aquí :)., pero así se demuestra la necesaria investigación previa.  Por otro lado, ¿puedes usar cualquier recurso de la biblioteca estándar o es una tarea o similar y debes implementar el algoritmo? Lo digo porque `collections.Counter` lo resuelve de forma inmediata.

Comment: ahi lo edite es lo q estoy intentando hacer!slds

Answer (score 0):

Aunque el concepto lo tienes, el principal problema de tu aproximación es que solo te valdría para contar las apariciones del primer item, además debes eliminar duplicados en la lista final.

Si no se pueden usar más que listas la idea sería la siguiente:

- Inicializamos una lista vacía que será nuestro contador, la lista de listas que al final retornaremos.
- Iteramos sobre cada item de la lista cuyos elementos queremos contar, por cada uno recorremos la lista contador y comparamos el item con lo almacenado en la posición 0 de cada sublista de contador, si coincide le agregamos 1 a la posición 2.
- Si tras recorrer `contador` entero no encontramos ninguna sublista con ese item, agregamos una nueva sublista de la forma `[item, 1]`.

---

```
def contador(lista):
    contador_list = []
    for item in lista:
        for cont in contador_list:
            if item == cont[0]:
                cont[1] += 1
                break
        else:
            contador_list.append([item, 1])
    return contador_list
```

No obstante, Python permite hacer esto de una forma muchísimo más eficiente y simple usando `collections.Counter`:

```
import collections

def contador(lista):
    return list(map(list, collections.Counter(lista).items()))
```

o:

```
import collections

def contador(lista):
    return [list(count) for count in collections.Counter(lista).items()]
```

Existe una solución intermedia que permite implementarlo de forma similar a `Counter`, pero sin importar nada, usando un diccionario estándar:

```
def contador(lista):
    contador_dict = dict.fromkeys(lista, 0)
    for item in lista:
        contador_dict[item] += 1
    return [list(cont) for cont in contador_dict.items()]
```

La salida esperada que muestras, `(['a', 2], ['b',2], ['c', 1])` es realmente una tupla de listas, no una lista de listas, si es ésto lo deseado basta con hacer:

```
return tuple(contador)
```

---

```
return tuple(map(list, collections.Counter(lista).items()))
```

---

```
return tuple(list(count) for count in collections.Counter(lista).items())
```

---

```
 return tuple(list(cont) for cont in contador_dict.items())
```

respectivamente para cada código anterior.

Comment: muchas gracias, no conocía esta collections.Counter y me funcionó bien!